# How to use mesh bisect in blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

I want to cut this 3d object to 2 pieces. I dont have bisect tool or knife tool. I can not use them i don't know why that is why i need your help.

Here is image of my edit view in blender 
[image]

And here is direct download link for my 3d object..

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BQVwPDAnwIFFAxrD5ps0cbvVqVH7iYrL/view?usp=sharing

thank you so much

p.s. I want to cut my model into 2 pieces .. but i can not find ADD tools with bisect in my blender.. anyone know solution?

Comment: @cegaton , 
Yes i did it. May I ask you do you know solution why i can not see ADD tools in edit mode and select bisect?

Comment: You are using curves. To use bisect or knife tools you would need to convert the curves to mesh. (Alt+C)